# Accepting Name for each Player

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a game. In the beginning of the program, I want to Accept the number of players and also their names. I tried to accept using a 2D Array, but it didn't work out well. Is there a way to Accept the number of players and also their names? Should I use structures? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single dimension (1D) `string` array can work if you don't want to associate any extra data like scores to each player. But if there will be extra data for each player, then I recommend using structures and creating a single dimension (1D) `struct` array.

For example:

```
typedef struct {
    string name;
    int score;
} Player;
```

For entering the number of players and the credentials, you can let the user input the number of players, then create a `Player` array where you'll loop through each element to enter the name. Like:

```
int numPlayers = 0;
cin >> numPlayers;

Player player[numPlayers];
for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
    cin >> player[i].name;
}
```

**Edit**: Use vectors if you want to have a non-fixed number of players. Use arrays if you want a fixed number of players.

Answer (score 1):

Use vectors!

```
int player_cnt;
cin >> player_cnt;

vector<string> player_names(player_cnt);
for (int i = 0; i < player_cnt; i++)
    cin >> player_names[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't usually need a 2D array for this, you can use a `std::vector<char>` to hold the players name and use the position on the vector to determine the player ID in case you need that.

Of course a struct is also an option, and you hold the instances of your struct in a vector as well. That way you can store additional information of the player inside the same array.

Comment: Why a `std::vector<char>` and not `std::vector<std::string>` ?

Comment: @Tobias that is a very good question. I have no idea what I was thinking when I wrote this. A std::string is the optimal structure to store text for this purpose.